# Custom UIView doesn't receive touch events

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

My app is reading a JSON feed of blog posts and displays them. I've created a subclass of UIView called PostView and hooked a nib to it. Displaying is working fine, however, I can't get any touch events to work.

In the nib I have a UIButton, whose function is supposed to be to perform a segue (to show the comments for the given post). I'm just trying to NSLog something but it's not working. I tried to put buttons after the for loop in code, and those actions work fine, so my addTarget method doesn't have errors.

I have also tried to set setUserInteractionEnabled to YES in multiple places, didnt help either. I really can't figure this one out.

Any suggestions?

update:

```
for (NSDictionary * post in json) {
    DMBasePostView *nextPost = [DMBasePostView alloc];
    nextPost = [newPost init];
    [nextPost setFrame:CGRectMake(...)];

    // (setting of post-specific stuffs here cut out...)

    // adding target for UIButton:
    [nextPost.showCommentsButton addTarget:self action:@selector(testMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.view addSubview:nextPost];
}
```

This is basically how I display posts in my ViewController. PostView has the necessary awakeFromNib method so it displays the nib layout correctly.

Comment: How are you hooking up your code to the XIB? That's a somewhat tricky thing to do that I don't see people do too often.

Comment: i have added an empty xib file, and its file owner to my PostView class. Then I added a UIView, and the control stuffs on top of it. I can display my this xib layout in my viewcontroller without any problems.

Comment: In your view hierarchy, the UIButton is child of what view?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you mean: i put a UIView initially on the empty xib, with the UIButton on this, and added it as a subview to my UIView subclass PostView.

Comment: So the views arrangments are PostView->View->Button?

Comment: Also please post the code in where you load the views from your xib to the viewcontroller

Comment: yes, thats the hierarchy. im posting the code in a few minutes as an update.

Comment: The common reason of not responding by UIControl on any view is they are out of bounds of the parent view. So make sure the UIButton is within bounds of its parent view.

Comment: @Jitendra I've already fixed it, and that was the problem exactly. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that I manipulated the PostView's height in my controller but not the added UIView subview's, and as a result the uibutton somehow got out of the bounds of its superview. I didn't think of it because it was still displayed correctly, but it didn't respond to touches. I had to fix the superview's height and it solved my problem.